# jQuery: return focus after loading dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, focus

is there a simple way to remember the element which had focus on before the loading dialog is shown, and return the focus to that element?
There is a search button on the page which sends an ajax request on keyboard press to fetch the data from the server. On each ajax request the modal loading dialog shows (notice that it is jquery dialog), and after the response, the focus on the search element is lost, and I want it back.

Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify - are you saying you want the focus to be on the search field after someone clicks close on a jQueryUI dialog? - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Ah, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I want the focus to be returned to the previously active element (just as jfriend00 assumed) - not specifically the search input.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57099835/339440

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you put the dialog up, you can save the location of the focus with this:

```
var origFocus = document.activeElement;
```

And, then after the dialog goes away, you can restore it:

```
origFocus.focus();
```